# linux/unix: script starting some command if some directory tree exists

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm a linux newbie, so pardon me if you don't understand me :)

I have a problem that I need to run a command `chmod 777 XXX` (XXX is directory) but I cant login to it, but I can push UNIX script which will be executed to do this. But the problem is that I don't know in which path this script is started/placed :).

IN DETAIL: I need script which will check if relative path (directory tree) `CCCC/YYY/XXX` exists on this machine somewhere and if it exists following command needs to be started on this directory `chmod 777 XXX`.  (XXX should be resolved to absolute path :))

I did some test with find, but no real result.

Comment: You need to find a specific directory structure `CCCC/YYY/XXX` wherever it happens to live on the disk and set the permissions of the `XXX` directory to `777`? And you don't know where that directory structure is going to be at all but you know the permissions will be wrong and need to be made *wide* open?

Comment: I know that  I will allow all hackers for access:), but the apache is set is such way that user cannot access this directory (this is MVC app, so apache is protecting this)

Comment: If there is a specific user on the system that needs access to the directory there are better ways of fixing that than `777` permissions. And you didn't answer the rest of my questions.

Comment: For first part of question: you are right. For previous question: no specific user.

Comment: Do you have at least a directory prefix under which that tree is going to live? Something more than `/`? What users need to access these apache files from local disk (and why do they need to do that)? Do they need to read them or also write them? Does `find /prefix -wholename '*/CCCC/YYY/XXX' -exec chmod 777` do what you want?

Comment: If you *must* use `chmod 777`, then you probably also want to set the "sticky bit"; see: `man chmod`.

Answer (score 1):

The `locate` command will help you here:

```
path_part=CCCC/YYY/XXX
if output=$( locate "$path_part" 2>/dev/null ); then
    grep "$path_part$" <<< "$output" |
    while IFS= read -r dir; do
        # do something in "$dir"
    done
fi
```

`locate` requires you to run `updatedb` -- your system may run it already periodically.

Comment: IMHO you're better off using `find` in most cases; disks today are usually fast enough for this (but it depends on the amount of files, how often you do this, etc.)